# Is it possible to receive push notifications in Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

When I try and call getToken() I receive the following error:

> An error occurred while retrieving token.  FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'register') (messaging/failed-service-worker-registration).
> at Ge (registerDefaultSw.ts:43:25)
> at updateSwReg.ts:28:11
> at Je (getToken.ts:43:9)

This works in standalone html but doesn't work in Chrome Extension.

I'm using FCM 9.2 and have service worker code in firebase-messaging-sw.js.  My manifest.json as the following format: